FastReport.Net RTF export issue
I am trying export RTF file using .NET 8 console application and FastReport.Core.Skia.Demo v2025.1.4 nuget package.
Questions:

Export result second page layout is automatically changed
How to set currency sign in report?


Please provide more details.

able to export my report in rtf file format but second page is layout automatically changed compared with report template.
